Can you draw a polygon with n vertices (n>5 is your choice) and at most n-5 reflex angles such that its visibility graph has 2n-3 edges?
I'm just curious whether there exists a polygon with n vertices (n>5 is your choice) and at most n-5 reflex angles such that its visibility graph has 2n-3 edges? I'm trying to build a tight example for Ghosh's first necessary condition of visibility graphs with less that n-4 reflex angles. You can review these conditions here.
I did it with n-4 reflex angles for n=10 here. I need to know if it can be done using less reflex angles.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
